# this point to {} in javascript lambda expression

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

```
const Test = function() {
  this.name = 'John'
  this.age = 100
}
Test.prototype.update = name => {
  console.log('this', this) // it display `{}`,why? I think it should be Test itself
  this.name = name
}
const instance = new Test()
instance.update('White')
```

`this` points to {}, not the Test function, it makes me confused.How does `this` work in lambda?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions does not receive `this`.

#### From Mozzila:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target.

`this` inside shorter sintax is pointing to global scope.

```js
var alpha='a';

const Test = function() {
  this.name = 'John'
  this.age = 100
}
Test.prototype.update = name => {
  console.log('this.alpha', this.alpha);
  this.name = name;
}
const instance = new Test()
instance.update('White')
console.log('this.name', this.name);
```

Comment: I know, lambda has no this with it. The `this` points to `this`which is from outer environment, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Before arrow functions, all new instances of a function would bind a new `this`.  In comparison, arrow functions do not and will use the `this` at the time of invocation.  In situations where this is a problem, arrows functions can be bound to any `this`.

This [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) goes into more detail, but one of the justifications for arrow functions was to avoid having to do some hijinks like assigning `var that = this;` and then invoking a `function`  that wanted to access a property on the `this` of the calling scope.

Comment: Funny how they just introduced another problem to fix a perceived problem... I swear these coffee script and compiled language developers will be the death of javaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see. @mkalish